# ionic 4 loss of session using href and switching back to app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I build a simple page and it renders a list of some items. These items have a href element to open it in browser. The trouble is that when user comes back all the class used to hold local variable gets reinitialized and breaks the app functionality. What is the correct way to handle this. I want to retain the data set. Below is my code for list and the variables in a service class

```
<ion-content>
<div  class="full-screen-bg">
    <div  *ngFor="let alb of core.albums">
        <ion-row><ion-col no-padding text-center><a href="{{alb.link}}"><img src="{{alb.image}}"></a></ion-col></ion-row>
        <ion-row><ion-col class="sg-title-text">{{alb.name}}</ion-col></ion-row>
     </div>
```

the service class that has variables and gets reset is

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoreService {
  loggedIn:boolean
  name:string

  constructor(public admob: Admob,
          public sgSvc:DataServiceService) { 
this.loggedIn = false

console.log("album constructor called:::" + this.loggedIn + " name:" + this.name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is save login user (username, token and expiration time) by StorageService, and for your CoreService should be try get it from StorageService and confirm it, if token is none or already over exporation time then it is mean user should be login again.

```
export class CoreService {
  //...
  public isAdmin = false;
  private token = false;
  public userSubject: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();
  //...
  constructor(/*...*/) {
    this.userSubject.subscribe(user => {
      if (user && user['role']) {
        if (user['role'] == 'admin') {
          this.isAdmin = true;
        } else {
          this.isAdmin = false;
        }
      }
    });
    this.getLocal('user').then(val => {
      this.userSubject.next(val);
    });
  }
  //...
}
//And for other component also subscribe same subject like
export class AppComponent /*...*/ {
  constructor(coreService: CoreService /*...*/) {
    this.coreService.userSubject.subscribe(user => {
      // your logic there
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Well there are many places user can go out of the app and come back. It feels a lot of places to put the code to check that. Is there a central gurranted place to check whenever app is in foreground again ?

Comment: My way is define subject/subscribe  in core service. Let me paste some in my answer.

Comment: whats advantage if i have to any how subscribe in all the <page>.ts over simply doing it in the ngOnInit() of every page.ts ?